# Set sidebar position disabled and hide page title through php wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, sidebar

I've created a plugin for wordpress that can auto post pages on demand
my problem is formatting this pages to a specific template

I need that when the post page is auto inserted in the DB, set the `Sidebar position` to disabled in order to have a full width page and hide the `page title`... this options appear in the dashboard and I can click on them one by one, but that has to be automatic, not manually.

```
 $my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $tituloFichaP1 ),
          'post_content'  => $content,
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1,
          'post_category' => array( 8,39 ),
          'post_type' => 'page',
          'post_parent' => $parentPost,
          'page_template' => 'microsite',
          'comment_status' => 'open',
 );

 wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

By the way, the page_template attribute `('page_template' => 'microsite')` doesn't work either. Te post is inserted but the template is set to default.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just go through you code, you have done a simple mistake, in "page_template" that should be a file name **(filename.php)** of your template not a template name . for ex. if your template **microsite's** file name is **microsite.php** than your code will be.

```
$my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $tituloFichaP1 ),
      'post_content'  => $content,
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_category' => array( 8,39 ),
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'post_parent' => $parentPost,
      'page_template' => 'microsite.php',
      'comment_status' => 'open',
  );
 wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: that's right, now the template is set to microsite template by default. 
The sidebar and the title still there, i think i have to concentrate now in add that behavior into the microsite template in order to hide the sidebar and the page title.
Thank you very much @Savan

Comment: For removing sidebar just comment the code get_sidebar(); and for page title that would be the_title();

Comment: this template doesn't have the function get_sidebar(); and  the_title();... but i get success by modifing some css. Thank you @Savan